# What file do i have to run in order to launch a screenlet from the terminal?

Tags: screenlets

I remember i had to run a python file a while ago but i can't remember where i have to find  and which one i have to run when i get there (i think there were many python files in each directory)

(to make it more specific : for example, how can i run the lyrics screenlet from the terminal?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... it really depends, the normal default screenlets should be located under /usr/share/screenlets/screenlets-pack-basic/ For example, the Clock screenlet starts with

```
usr/share/screenlets/screenlets-pack-basic/Clock/ClockScreenlet.py
```

`> /dev/null`

but if i remember right, after installing screenlets, a new menu entry appears in ubuntu menu. The "other" menu entry. There you can find some screenlets, and there, looking at the Launcher Command, you can see the command which starts the screenlet. so i would look in either usr/share/screenlets/ or usr/local/share/screenlets

Comment: thanks, i think i found it - sorry for the delay i must have missed your message

Answer (score 0):

For me it's `python -u $HOME/.screenlets/Lyrics/LyricsScreenlet.py`. I recall I got it off Gnome-Look and unzipped it there.